# Как получить атрибут(class, id, data...) динамически добавленного элемента? JS

Tags: javascript, jquery

Приветствую) Помогите пожалуйста)) 
При Ajax запросе динамически создаётся элемент на странице.
Как получить атрибут динамически добавленного элемента при клике на него? 
В консоли *(main.js:421 Uncaught TypeError: this.attr is not a function)*

```
//Функция которая вызывается в success
function moveAjax(answerAjax){

  var objAjax = answerAjax;

  (function addBtn(answerAjax){
    let tabBtns = $('.tab-btns');
    for(let i = 0; i < objAjax.length; i++){
      var btnData = objAjax[i].data;
      //Динамическое добавление элемента
      $(tabBtns).append('<li><span data="' + btnData + '">' + objAjax[i].name + '</span></li>');
      console.log(objAjax[i].name);  
    };
  })();
  console.log(objAjax);

  (function(){
    //Обработчик событий на динамически добавлены элкмкнт
    $(".tab-btns>li").on("click", "span", function(){
      console.log(this.attr("data")); //Попытка получить атрибут "data" динамически добавленного элемента 
    })
  })();
};

//Запрос
$.ajax({
  dataType: "json",
  url: 'js/json/prices/prices.json',
  cache: false,
  error: function(XHR, status, error) { console.log(status+' '+error); },
  success: function(answerAjax) { 
    moveAjax(answerAjax); 
  }
});
```

Comment: `$(this).attr(...)` - здесь нужна обертка jQuery. `tabBtns.append(` - а здесь не нужна.

Comment: Спасибо) Очень помогли)